# Led light, in the off position, on a separate circuit, flashes when exhaust fan is turned on

Tags: led

Background:

3 year home, light in shower is on a separate circuit from the exhaust fan, with light in the off position, light will flicker when exhaust fan is turned on.  The light is not integrated into the exhaust fan (about a foot apart).  Where is the current leakage coming from?  Should I worry given that it is the shower stall?

Comment: Where does the LED get its neutral? Where does the exhaust fan get its neutral?  Is the light in the shower GFCI protected (i.e. by a GFCI device located elsewhere)?

Answer (score 2):

The electric field from the fan is causing the flicker in your light even though they're on different circuits. You had the same situation before but didn't notice it because you probably had incandescent bulbs. LED bulbs take a fraction of the current that incandescent bulbs take so now you notice the flicker. this is not something to worry about.

Comment: I agree with JACK. Not only do LED bulbs take a fraction of the power an incandescent bulb does, they have no "buffer".  They react INSTANTLY to power variations. The filament in an incandescent bulb is a glowing hot piece of metal that takes a small amount of time (1/4 - 1/2 of a second)  to cool enough for voltage variations to be  noticeable.  I'm hoping a manufacturer will incorporate a capacitor into the power supply of LED bulbs to minimize that annoying flicker.

Comment: I'm not so sure, my spider sense is tingling about some crossed-neutral issues.  That's especially important since the light in the shower needs GFCI protection, and obviously GFCI wouldn't work with a crossed neutral.